# Does carbon form a gas in the absense of oxygen?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, phase-diagram

If I take pure carbon and heat it in an inert atmospher, at what temperature will it vaporize into carbon gas?

Comment: All elements have a vapor pressure, which is a function of temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the periodic table?
https://www.ptable.com/?lang=en

melting point:

> Diamond: 3823 K
>
> Graphite: 3800 K

boiling point:

> Graphite: 5100 K

Sublimation point:

> Graphite: 3915 K (unspecified pressure)

Although they don't say under what atmosphere they are melting/boiling/sublimating the carbon.